# Angular 7: NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular7

I am tring to show the response in the display but keep getting this error in angular 7. I tried to check other solutions but didn't help.
    ExpensesComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ 
    supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only 
    supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

here is the response for my request in console.
content: Array(4)

```
0: {id: 2, description: "LED TV", expenseDate: "2019-04- 
   11T18:00:00.000+0000", expenseAmount: 2000}
    1: {id: 3, description: "LED TV 2", expenseDate: "2019-04- 
    11T18:00:00.000+0000", expenseAmount: 2000}
    2: {id: 4, description: "LED TV 3", expenseDate: "2019-04- 
    11T18:00:00.000+0000", expenseAmount: 13000}
    3: {id: 5, description: "LED TV 4", expenseDate: "2019-04- 
    11T18:00:00.000+0000", expenseAmount: 14000}
```

Here is the function which should set these response to a local variable.

```
expenseList : Expense[];
refreshExpensePage(){
   this.expenseDataService.retriveAllExpenses(this.page).subscribe(
   res=>{console.log(res); 
    console.log(res);
     this.expenseList = res; 
  }
 );
```

Here is  the expense class.

```
 export class Expense{
  constructor(
  public id:number,
  public description : string,
  public expenseDate: Date,
  public expenseAmount: number
    ){
   }
 }
```

And here is the html which should show the data in a table.

```
<tr *ngFor='let expense of expenseList'>
    <td>{{expense.id}}</td>
     <td>{{expense.description}}</td>
     <td>{{expense.expenseDate|date}}</td>
     <td><button (click) = "editExpenseById(expense.id)" 
      class="btn 
     btn-success">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button (click) = "deleteExpenseById(expense.id)" 
     class="btn 
     btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating class with constructor try defining as interface to define the object.

```
export interface Person {
 id:number;
 description : string;
 expenseDate: any;
 expenseAmount: number;
}
```

and in component import the interface incase its defined in different file, then declare the interface as default data type

```
expenseList : Person[];
```

then assign the appropriate array of object in **expenseList**

all the best